# Rows of flexible and fixed div's within full-size window

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a mobile/desktop chat application that is supposed to utilize the entire screen. The bottom `<div>` shown in yellow can be fixed-height if it needs to be.

presently it's Absolutely positioned to the bottom of the window.

My problem: the top `<div>`, in cyan, doesn't fit to the rest of the window, regardless of whether I use padding, margin, border, etc. Presently it *appears* to allow the content to wrap, but that's only because the bottom overwrites the scroll bar.

[image: Chat application]

My only solution so far is to have a final `<div>` or `<br>` that pads the end of the scrollable div, but that doesn't make the div smaller, or make the scroll bars properly align.

[Here is my source code so far in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FEuQy/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This style code basically sums up what I'm doing to compensate for my issue. (Instead of, say, using HTML tables.) This may not be the best solution.

```
#topPart {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 40px; /* or however high the bottom is */
}

#bottomPart {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 40px; /* same as above */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you edit your CSS and set the DIV with the chat text a class like .break-word and then in CSS declare it with word-wrap:

```
.break-word {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Unsure on the covering of scrollbars.  You should post your code for others to view and might be able to pick something out.

Comment: I did post the source code on Fiddle, the link isn't as obvious anymore (it was edited, I'll re-edit). But it's still at the bottom of the question.